# IPC through a SHM for C++ and concurrent memory accesses

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-memory

I am trying to improve the performance of a framework I use.

Currently it makes use of a shared memory space(shm), to allow for inter-process communication between two C++ threads. Control to the SHM is passed through a semaphore. This is the current system which works quite well, albeit slightly slower than what I'd like, and with a need of flags for communication.

I have thought of using a master/slave configuration with the signals only being driven by either side. Hence a signal such as Slave_Ready would be written by the slave, and read by the master to show that the slave can take a request.

I would expect this behaviour to be supported, since only one side is writing to a signal ever. However, when the slave is polling the master-driven signals, the master seems unable to change the values of the signals. I've done this in Eclipse, and when I try to step through the write instruction it just doesn't get executed. This is what it looks like :

```
shmp->MREADY = true; // in the same time the slave is polling this signal.
```

So this instruction never goes through. 
By my understanding, a read/write should be irrelevant. The write should go through, or it should be handled as an atomic request by the memory controller. Even if a read happens half-way through a write, I do not have an issue with corrupted data. If the read sees a true, it goes through and accesses data that was written before the ready signal was asserted. If it reads a false, it accesses the signals the next cycle. Either way the data integrity is preserved. Hence I would expect that this would work without issue, however there is obviously something at play here.

Is it that concurrent read/writes aren't supported? Does the constant spam of polling read request drown out the write request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using C++11's `std::atomic<>` for the `MREADY` member. Or at least issue [`std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) after the assignment.

Comment: Hey, cheers for the answer, I resolved it before you answered. In the end it was enough to declare the shared members as volatile. I believe what was happening was the compiler optimizing away accesses that appeared in a while(true) loop.

Comment: @JohnNikolaou: That might be good enough for AMD64 architecture but it might not be enough for other architectures. You should add the barrier as well.